# How to communicate arduino with Matlab

Tags: arduino-uno

I have been working on a project which deals with analysing data from sensors to matlab. How do i establish this communication. Please help me

Comment: Presumably you need to find out how to do serial-port communication from matlab.  It's not clear that this is the best stack exchange site for that part of the problem, though the arduino part of message creation/parsing could best fit here.